# full outer join 3 tables with matching index in Postgre SQL

Tags: sql, outer-join

I have an SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.z = B.z WHERE A.z = 1 OR B.z = 1
```

where A.z and B.z are primary keys.

The purpose is to do a full outer join on two tables whilst their primary keys match a given value - so that only one row is returned.

But I got confused on how to extend it to 3 or more tables. The restriction that their primary keys match a given index so that only one row is return in total remains. How do you do it?

Comment: If you only want one row to return, then is a full outer join what you are looking for?  A full outer join returns all the rows from both tables and will put null for the key if there is not match.

Comment: tell us something about your data constrains (or write an example) please, because the first query could return lots and lots of rows for arbitrary data...

Comment: @jle The idea is that if even 1 out of 3 tables has a row for the given key, I want it.

Comment: everyone - corrected an error in the sql I posted. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, note that in the provided query, the `FULL OUTER JOIN` that you request could be rewritten as:

```
         SELECT *
           FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHERE z = 1) A
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B WHERE z = 1) B ON A.z = B.z
```

which makes (IMO) more clear what the data sources are and what the join condition is. For a moment, with your `WHERE` condition, I had the feeling that you wanted actually an INNER JOIN.

With this you can extend more easily probably:

```
         SELECT *
           FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHERE z = 1) A
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B WHERE z = 1) B ON A.z = B.z
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM C WHERE z = 1) C ON COALESCE(A.z,B.z) = C.z
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM D WHERE z = 1) D ON COALESCE(A.z,B.z,C.z) = D.z
```

Comment: Hey, I made a mistake in the question. Can you have a relook? Also, what if rows in B,C exist with B.z = C.z but no corresponding row is in A exists?

Comment: This doesn't work because A is joined with B and A is also joined with C, but no simultaneous join between B and C. Tried the case where A doesn't have a row with z=1, but B and C do. Got two rows instead of one.

Comment: Thanks! That worked - I didn't know what COALESCE was before. Though you can reformulate the query back to the format in my question which is shorter and looks simpler to me.